# How to mask out wireless by blocking a neighboring WiFi Access Point

Tags: wifi, block, signals

I surely hope this question is not a duplicate of another; I had difficulty finding a cut and dry solution for this on my own, so I thought I might have some luck sharing it with the Hive Mind of collective human consciousness that is the Stack.

My goal is simple: I seek to broadcast a signal within a very small space (approximately 1000 square feet) that will block wireless access to a specific Access Point. In doing so, I am hoping to avoid blocking access to any other access points in this airspace. There is one specific unsecured Metropolitan Area Network in my area that represents a potential security liability.

I have the requisite authority to broadcast a signal within a short distance to essentially "scramble" this particular signal. I do not, however, have the capacity to make any changes to the ACTUAL WiFi access point in question; therefore, I cannot manually set up firewall rules or a MAC address filter to the AP that needs to be masked.

I do, however, have control over all other access points in this airspace, and can change their ESSIDs, channels and other configuration at will. I can also set up additional APs if need be, in order to try to close off access to this network.

One method I had considered would be to set up an BackTrack instance, or DD-WRT router, or HyperWRT/Tomato router, with the goal of aggressively intercepting wireless access point association requests for the wireless network that I want to block... I have not given this a go, yet, as I had hoped to confirm that it is the correct solution before attempting to employ it.

Any help that can be offered is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like you're effectively trying to do something along the lines of "jamming" the wireless network but for only the SSID. Jamming networks and signals can cause legal issues. Hmm. I guess your goal is to stop people from connecting to this unsecured network?

Comment: If you are so concerned about your users connecting to this network, then you ought to enforce policy on their devices such that they cannot choose arbitrary networks to join.

Comment: Build a Faraday Cage around the secure area.  This will passively block all radio signals from coming into the area; and it's totally legal.

Comment: You can deploy a blacklist of wi-fi SSIDs to your client machines through an Active Directory GPO.

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing is illegal in the US:   http://transition.fcc.gov/eb/jammerenforcement/jamfaq.pdf